# Determine height of UIWebView content (embedded in UITableViewCell)

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiwebviewdelegate

I've got a UITableView holding `UIWebView`s of variable height, and the user has the ability to edit the content of each web view. The content of each cell (a web view) is linked to a `NSManagedObject` subclass that has the height of the content stored as `contentHeight`. When a new set of content is initially created, it is filled in with a default set of data that has a set height, so there is no issue there.

My problem arises when the user edits the content of a web view; I need to figure out the height of the new content and update the tableview accordingly. I've already set up the logic for updating the saved `contentHeight` variable for the corresponding object, but I cannot find a reliable method to determine the height of the new content. Below I've listed a few of the methods I've tried and haven't been able to make work. *ANY* help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stumped for over an hour now :(

**FAILED METHODS:**

```
[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] floatValue];

[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight"] floatValue];

[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];

[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('sdcontent').offsetHeight"] floatValue];

CGRect webViewFrame = [webView frame];
CGRect temp = webViewFrame;
webViewFrame.size.height = 1;
[webView setFrame:webViewFrame];
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
webViewFrame.size = fittingSize;
[webView setFrame:temp];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works but only when

- making webview small (like 5px)
- load it and wait for finish
- calling sizeToFit on it then
- getting the size THEN

advertisement: :D see my M42WebviewTableViewCell class on github which struggles with this